# Why isn't the text showing up?

Tags: java, text

I am making a text based game, and my code works fine until this line when i type in "why" it doesn't print "test".

```
System.out.println( "Fallout: Master's dialogue");
System.out.println("  ");
System.out.println( " So, what shall it be? Do you join the Unity or do you die here? Join! Die! Join! Die! ");
System.out.print( "> ");
Go = keyboard.nextLine();

if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("join"))
{
    System.out.println("Excellent. Your talents will be useful. But first you must tell me everything about your vault.");}
    System.out.print(">  ");
    Look = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("why"))
    {System.out.println("TEST");}
    System.out.print(">  ");
    Look = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: I think you should have written `Look.equalsIgnoreCase("why")`

Comment: why did "join" work in the previous one then.

Comment: @Coder32 Because in `join`, you used the proper variable. `Go`, will only contain the `String` "join". You need to use the `Look` variable

Comment: Because Look and Go are different variables

Comment: Did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `Go` and `Look` are string variables.

At the start of the code, you read the user input and stored it in `Go`:

```
Go = keyboard.nextLine();
```

And then you checked whether `Go` is `join`:

```
if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("join"))
```

This is all fine and good.

Then, you read user input a second time, and stored it in `Look`:

```
Look = keyboard.nextLine();
```

But you incorrectly checked `Go` instead:

```
if (Go.equalsIgnoreCase("why"))
```

`Go` has not been changed. `Go` is still "join", so the condition is never true.

You should check `Look` instead:

```
if (Look.equalsIgnoreCase("why"))
```